# Why append part does not work in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In the code below after I upload my document I wrote a loop which is supposed to add some images into a division called Divnavigation, but this part doesn't work.

Also when I make it uncommented even my documentViewer can not be loaded. Am I allowed to add something to my division from AJAX call?

```
function navigate(target) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Download", "Patient")',
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: { 'filepath': target },
        success: function (results) {
            // documentViewer.loadDocument(results);               
            documentViewer.uploadDocumentFromUri(results[results.length -1]);
            documentViewer.addEventListener(gnostice.EventNames.afterDocumentLoad, function (eventArgs) {
                document.getElementById("TotalPage").textContent = documentViewer.viewerManager.pageCount;
                document.getElementById("pageNumber").value = documentViewer.viewerManager.currentPage;

                $("#Divnavigation").empty();
                //Get all images  with the help of model
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    $("#Divnavigation").append(" <ul> " +
                                     "<li>" +
                                     "<img src=" + results[i] + ">" + "</img>" +
                                     "<a href=" + @Url.Action("Download", "Patient") + ">" + "</a>" +
                                      "</li>"
                                + "</ul>");
                }
            });
            //showImages();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error occured');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: how your action method looks like?

Comment: yes you can, but are you sure you are getting the right results ? is it the append not working ? or the result you are getting is not correct ? 
can you post the html code and your action code

Comment: You are not doing it from the ajax callback but from an eventListener of your documentViewer. Does it even get triggered?

Answer (score -1):

Hi Answer to your question first:

Am I allowed to add something to my division from .ajax call?

you are 100% allowed to add something to your division from .ajax call. there is no doubt in that. I done personally many times

This time you are not getting because of some other reason.

Now my suggestion is try using  `$("#Divnavigation").html().`

Official doc: https://api.jquery.com/html/

so first as first step  try by putting simple html like this `$("#Divnavigation").html("<p>test</p>)` and see whether you get the output. if you get then change, html string whatever you want  ,that can be hardcoded string or even you can get that string  from the action method.

Hope above information was helpful. kindly share your thoughts

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answers..I think the problem is related to image path....because when I add something simple like $("#Divnavigation").html("<p>test</p>) everything is ok but it does not work with images....I will check it...